# Insect lays eggs with Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ denotes the number of eggs; poisson-distributed with parameter $λ$. Each egg hatches independently of the other eggs with probability $p$. Find the mean number of descendants.

We know that $X\sim Po(\lambda)$. I think that we have to find
$E(X|Y=1)$ where $Y$ is an event that describes whether or not it hatch.

Then we have
$$ E(X|Y)=\frac{1}{P(Y)} \int_{Y=1} X(\omega)dP $$
since $P(Y)=p$ we have
$$E(X|Y)= \frac{1}{p} \int_{Y=1} X(\omega)dP $$

and I am stuck here. I guess i should use the probability density function for Poisson distribution but I am not sure about integration limits. However I am not sure if my idea is correct.

Comment: Hint: express the number of hatched descendants as $\sum_{k=1}^XY_k$ where $Y_k$ are IID binary random variables.

Answer (score 1):

> where Y is an event that describes whether or not it hatch.

Which "it"?  There are $X$ eggs, *each* hatching independently with probability $p$.

Rather, let $Y$ be *that which you wish to count*: the descendants. This is clearly the count for eggs which are lain and hatch.

The count for successes among a number of independent trials with identical success rate $p$ is, *by definition*, a Binomial Distributed Random Variable.

$\qquad Y\mid X\sim \mathcal{Bin}(X, p)$

So, begin here:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\[1ex] &=\sum_{x=0}^\infty\sum_{y=0}^x y\,\mathsf P(X=x)\,\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)\\[1ex]&= \sum_{x=0}^\infty\sum_{y=0}^x y\cdot\dfrac{\lambda^x\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}{x!}\cdot\dfrac{x!}{y!~(x-y)!}\,p^y\,(1-p)^{x-y}\\[1ex]&=\sum_{y=0}^\infty\sum_{x=y}^\infty\dfrac{y\,\lambda^{y+x-y}\,p^y\,(1-p)^{x-y}~\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}{y!~(x-y)!}\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$

Comment: Alternatively: Each descendant occurs independently of all possible others with egg-occurrence rate $\lambda$ and hatching-success rate $p$.  So...